# Are facebook requests using iOS FB SDK multi-threaded

Tags: facebook, ios6

My scenario:

I am making multiple facebook requests using the iOS facebook SDK. However, I am not sure if those requests are happening all on a single thread(of course different than UI) or multiple threads.

I want to essentially check status of each friend in my friendlist and am trying to see if there is a way to improve performance. Just using the SDK, it seems they are asynchronous requests, but don't think they are happening on multiple threads.

Is that true? Anyway to kick off multiple threads in a responsible manner that can help performance?

Answer (score 0):

Facebook does not handle its requests in a multi-threaded fashion (they are asynchronous, like you said), but you can send Facebook requests on threads that you create yourself in iOS. Check out this guide from Apple to learn about threading on iOS: https://developer.apple.com/library/mac/#documentation/Cocoa/Conceptual/Multithreading/CreatingThreads/CreatingThreads.html

Answer (score 0):

You should be able to achieve the result you need with a single API call:

```
/me/friends?limit=10&fields=posts.limit(1).fields(story)
```

for example, will return ten friends, and the story field of their most recent post.

```
/me/friends?limit=10&fields=statuses.limit(1).fields(message)
```

is something similar for the ./statuses connection. There's paging too, if you need.

You can use the left hand query builder of the Graph Explorer (https://developers.facebook.com/tools/explorer) to build out these expanded field queries, and there's more info here: https://developers.facebook.com/docs/reference/api/field_expansion/